# Kafka tests failing intermittently if not starting/stopping kafka each time

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, scalatest, reactive-streams

I'm trying to run some integration tests for a data stream using an embedded kafka cluster. When executing all the tests in a different environment than my local, the tests are failing due to some internal state that's not removed properly.

I can get the all the tests running on the non-local environment when I start/stop the kafka cluster before/after each test but I only want to start and stop the cluster once, at the beginning and at the end of the execution of my suite of tests.

I tried to remove the local streams state but that didn't seem to work:

```
override protected def afterEach(): Unit = KStreamTestUtils.purgeLocalStreamsState(properties)
```

Is there a way to get my suit of tests running without having to start/stop cluster each time?

Right below there are the relevant classes.

```
class TweetStreamProcessorSpec extends FeatureSpec
  with MockFactory with GivenWhenThen with Eventually with BeforeAndAfterEach with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  val CLUSTER: EmbeddedKafkaCluster = new EmbeddedKafkaCluster
  val TEST_TOPIC: String = "test_topic"
  val properties = new Properties()

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    CLUSTER.start()
    CLUSTER.createTopic(TEST_TOPIC, 1, 1)
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = CLUSTER.stop()

  // if uncommenting these lines tests works
  // override def afterEach(): Unit = CLUSTER.stop() 
  // override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = CLUSTER.start()

  def createProducer: KafkaProducer[String, TweetEvent] = {
    val properties = Map(
      KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringSerializer].getName,
      VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[ReflectAvroSerializer[TweetEvent]].getName,
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> CLUSTER.bootstrapServers(),
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG -> CLUSTER.schemaRegistryUrlForcedToLocalhost()
    )
    new KafkaProducer[String, TweetEvent](properties)
  }

  def kafkaConsumerSettings: KafkaConfig = {
    val bootstrapServers = CLUSTER.bootstrapServers()
    val schemaRegistryUrl = CLUSTER.schemaRegistryUrlForcedToLocalhost()
    val zookeeper = CLUSTER.zookeeperConnect()

    KafkaConfig(
      ConfigFactory.parseString(
        s"""
        akka.kafka.bootstrap.servers = "$bootstrapServers"
        akka.kafka.schema.registry.url = "$schemaRegistryUrl"
        akka.kafka.zookeeper.servers = "$zookeeper"
        akka.kafka.topic-name = "$TEST_TOPIC"
        akka.kafka.consumer.kafka-clients.key.deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        akka.kafka.consumer.kafka-clients.value.deserializer = ${classOf[ReflectAvroDeserializer[TweetEvent]].getName}
        akka.kafka.consumer.kafka-clients.client.id = client1
        akka.kafka.consumer.wakeup-timeout=20s
        akka.kafka.consumer.max-wakeups=10
      """).withFallback(ConfigFactory.load()).getConfig("akka.kafka")
    )
  }

  feature("Logging tweet data from kafka topic") {

    scenario("log id and payload when consuming a update tweet event") {
      publishEventsToKafka(List(upTweetEvent))
      val logger = Mockito.mock(classOf[Logger])
      val pipeline = new TweetStreamProcessor(kafkaConsumerSettings, logger)
      pipeline.start
      eventually(timeout(Span(5, Seconds))) {
        Mockito.verify(logger, Mockito.times(1)).info(s"updating tweet uuid=${upTweetEvent.getUuid}, payload=${upTweetEvent.getPayload}")
      }
      pipeline.stop
    }

    scenario("log id when consuming a delete tweet event") {
      publishEventsToKafka(List(delTweetEvent))
      val logger = Mockito.mock(classOf[Logger])
      val pipeline = new TweetStreamProcessor(kafkaConsumerSettings, logger)
      pipeline.start
      eventually(timeout(Span(5, Seconds))) {
        Mockito.verify(logger, Mockito.times(1)).info(s"deleting tweet uuid=${delTweetEvent.getUuid}")
      }
      pipeline.stop
    }
  }
}


class TweetStreamProcessor(kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig, logger: Logger)
  extends Lifecycle with TweetStreamProcessor with Logging {

  private var control: Control = _
  private val valueDeserializer: Option[Deserializer[TweetEvent]] = None

  // ...

  def tweetsSource(implicit mat: Materializer): Source[CommittableMessage[String, TweetEvent], Control] =
    Consumer.committableSource(tweetConsumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(kafkaConfig.topicName))

  override def start: Future[Unit] = {
    control = tweetsSource(materializer)
      .mapAsync(1) { msg =>
        logTweetEvent(msg.record.value())
          .map(_ => msg.committableOffset)
      }.batch(max = 20, first => CommittableOffsetBatch.empty.updated(first)) { (batch, elem) =>
      batch.updated(elem)
    }
      .mapAsync(3)(_.commitScaladsl())
      .to(Sink.ignore)
      .run()

    Future.successful()
  }


  override def stop: Future[Unit] = {
    control.shutdown()
      .map(_ => Unit)
  }
}
```

Any help over this would be much appreciated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact failure you are seeing? Also, what is `EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster` -- did you copy it from Apache Kafka or ...? Also I don't quite understand what your doing locally vs. in your "non-local environment": if you are running integration tests such as the code snippet above, everything runs locally, no? I suppose you might be re-using e.g. input/output topic names across tests (plus `application.id` for Kafka Streams), and thus run into test issues.

Comment: ¨wanted but not invoked¨ exception is thrown. By locally, I mean my on machine and non-locally, in Jenkins. When executing `mvn clean tests` in Jenkins, they fail. `EmbeddedKafkaCluster` is a wrapper of Kafkserver, a local schema registry and zookeeper - a external library I didn't write myself. Unless I push up all code there is no way you can help me out with so maybe this question should be removed. Thanks for the helpl @miguno

Comment: Could it be an issue with your Jenkins environment?  For example, perhaps the Jenkins server doesn't have enough memory to start a Kafka broker, Zookeeper instance, and a Confluent schema registry, plus your test code -- and thus the test fails?

Comment: Hm, that was an interesting thought but in that scenario I guess I shouldn't get a "TimeOutException: wanted but not invoked" and it would be more an OutOfMemory or something like that. Finally I decided to start/stop after each test and track the issue in the future, when I get more understanding of what that library is doing.